# Swap row values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have question about SQL Server

Source: `emp`

```
id      | name  | check |deptname 
100     |  a    |  1    |ceo   
100     |  b    |  2    |hr
100     |  c    |  3    |po
100     |  d    |  5    |no
101     |  a    |  1    |pm
101     |  b    |  5    |ceo
102     |  a    |  1    |rn
102     |  b    |  2    |han
```

Here same id have check 2 and 5 values then we need to replace  check values to 2 check values for that id.

Based on above table I want load/output data into target table like below

Target : `emp1`

```
id      | name  | check |deptname
100     |  a    |  1    |ceo
100     |  d    |  2    |hr
100     |  c    |  3    |po
101     |  a    |  1    |pm
101     |  b    |  5    |ceo
102     |  a    |  1    |rn
102     |  b    |  2    |han
```

and  I tried like below

```
select 
    a1.id,
    a1.name,
    isnull(a2.[check],a1.[check]) as [check]
from 
    emp as a1
left outer join 
    emp as a2 on a2.id = a1.id
              and a1.[check] in (2,5)
              and a2.[check] in (2,5)
              and a2.[check] <> a1.[check]
where 
    a2.id is null
    or (a1.[check] = 5
        and a2.[check] = 2)
```

That query does not return the right result.

Please tell me how to write query to get the expected output in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that:

```
select
  e1.id,
  isnull(e2.name, e1.name) as name,
  e1.[check],
  e1.deptname
from emp e1
left outer join emp e2
  on e2.id = e1.id and e1.[check] = 2 and e2.[check] = 5
where
  not exists (select 1 from emp e3 where e3.id = e1.id and 
      e1.[check] = 5 and e3.[check] = 2)
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f47d2c/1)

Comment: Your question says to change "check" values, but you're actually changing names, because deptname remains from the row with value 2.